# Implementation of normalizing flows in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I've been trying to implement a simple version of normalizing flows with Keras, as explained in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05770.pdf

My problem is that the loss is always -infinity, and I can't get what I did wrong. Can anybody help me ?

Here is the procedure:

1. the encoder generates vectors of size `latent_dim = 100`. These are `z_mean, z_log_var, u, b, w`.
2. From `z_mean` and `z_log_var`, using the reparametrization trick I can sample `z_0` ~ `N(z_mean, z_log_var)`.
3. Then I can compute `log(abs(1+u.T.dot(psi(z_0))))`
4. Then I can compute `z_1`

Here is the code for those four steps:

```
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args

    # sample epsilon according to N(O,I)
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0.,
                              std=epsilon_std)

    # generate z0 according to N(z_mean, z_log_var)
    z0 = z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon
    print('z0', z0)
    return z0

def logdet_loss(args):
    z0, w, u, b = args
    b2 = K.squeeze(b, 1)
    beta = K.sum(tf.multiply(w, z0), 1)  # <w|z0>
    linear_trans = beta + b2  # <w|z0> + b

    # change u2 so that the transformation z0->z1 is invertible
    alpha = K.sum(tf.multiply(w, u), 1)  # 
    diag1 = tf.diag(K.softplus(alpha) - 1 - alpha)
    u2 = u + K.dot(diag1, w) / K.sum(K.square(w)+1e-7)
    gamma = K.sum(tf.multiply(w,u2), 1)

    logdet = K.log(K.abs(1 + (1 - K.square(K.tanh(linear_trans)))*gamma) + 1e-6)

    return logdet

def transform_z0(args):
    z0, w, u, b = args
    b2 = K.squeeze(b, 1)
    beta = K.sum(tf.multiply(w, z0), 1)

    # change u2 so that the transformation z0->z1 is invertible
    alpha = K.sum(tf.multiply(w, u), 1)
    diag1 = tf.diag(K.softplus(alpha) - 1 - alpha)
    u2 = u + K.dot(diag1, w) / K.sum(K.square(w)+1e-7)
    diag2 = tf.diag(K.tanh(beta + b2))

    # generate z1
    z1 = z0 + K.dot(diag2,u2) 
    return z1
```

Then here is the loss (where `logdet` is defined above)

```
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = K.mean(objectives.categorical_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean), -1)
    ln_q0z0 = K.sum(log_normal2(z0, z_mean, z_log_var, eps=1e-6), -1)
    ln_pz1 = K.sum(log_stdnormal(z1), -1)
    result = K.mean(logdet + ln_pz1 + xent_loss - ln_q0z0)
    return result
```

Comment: it seems that the latent variables have fastly increasing norms, after the first epoch it's already more than 1e6

Answer (score 2):

I modified the Keras tutorial on VAE here : https://github.com/sbaurdlp/keras-iaf-mnist

If someone is interested to look...
Strangely adding more layers doesn't improve performance, and I can't see what is wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't make it work, I have tried to implement the normalizing flow described in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04934.pdf) paper: *Improved Variational Inference
with Inverse Autoregressive Flow*

However I still meet the same problem of diverging loss (towards -infinity), which makes no sense. There must be a problem with my implementation.

Here are the important parts:

```
# the encoder
h = encoder_block(x)  # a convnet taking proteins as input (matrices of size 400x22), I don't describe it since it isn't very important
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
h_ = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
encoder = Model(x, [z_mean,z_log_var, h_])

# the latent variables (only one transformation to keep it simple)
latent_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim, 2), batch_shape=(batch_size, latent_dim, 2))
hl = Convolution1D(1, filter_length, activation="relu", border_mode="same")(latent_input)
hl = Reshape((latent_dim,))(hl)
mean_1 = Dense(latent_dim)(hl)
std_1 = Dense(latent_dim)(hl)
latent_model = Model(latent_input, [mean_1, std_1])

# the decoder
decoder_input = Input((latent_dim,), batch_shape=(batch_size, latent_dim))
decoder=decoder_block()  # a convnet that I don't describe
x_decoded_mean = decoder(decoder_input)
generator = Model(decoder_input, x_decoded_mean)

# the VAE
z_mean, z_log_var, other = encoder(vae_input)
eps = Lambda(sample_eps, name='sample_eps')([z_mean, z_log_var, other])
z0 = Lambda(sample_z0, name='sample_z0')([z_mean, z_log_var, eps])
l = Lambda(sample_l, name='sample_l')([eps, z_log_var])
mean, std = latent_model(merge([Reshape((latent_dim,1))(z0), Reshape((latent_dim,1))(other)], mode="concat", concat_axis=-1))
z = Lambda(transform_z0)([z0, mean, std])
l = Lambda(transform_l)([l, std])
x_decoded_mean = generator(z)
vae = Model(vae_input, x_decoded_mean)

# and here is the loss
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = K.mean(objectives.categorical_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean), -1)
    ln_q0z0 = K.sum(log_normal2(z0, z_mean, z_log_var), -1)
    ln_pz1 = K.sum(log_stdnormal(z), -1)
    result = K.mean(l + ln_pz1 + xent_loss - ln_q0z0)
    return result
```

Here are the utils functions I use above in the `Lambda` layers:

```
def sample_eps(args):

    # sample epsilon according to N(O,I)
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0.,
                              std=epsilon_std)

    return epsilon

def sample_z0(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var, epsilon = args
    # generate z0 according to N(z_mean, z_log_var)
    z0 = z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon
    return z0

def sample_l(args):
    epsilon, z_log_var = args
    l = -0.5*K.sum(z_log_var + epsilon**2 + K.log(2*math.pi), -1)
    return l

def transform_z0(args):
    z0, mean, std = args
    z = z0
    sig_std = K.sigmoid(std)
    z *= sig_std
    z += (1-sig_std)*mean
    return z

def transform_l(args):
    l, std = args
    sig_std = K.sigmoid(std)
    l -= K.sum(K.log(sig_std+1e-8), -1)
    return l
```